# Azure Mobile App Service

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I would like to create a mobile app with Xamarin Forms and would like to use the new [Azure Mobile App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started/#) PaaS service. This mobile app shall be available also to users which uses my services from a web site and not only from a mobile device.

In regards to Authentication how can I have a single authentication point available either from a web site as well as from the mobile app?

Does anyone have suggestions on how to design this architecture?

Answer (score 3):

The Azure App Service, the Mobile Apps backend service is really just a Web API running in Web Apps (think web site + mobile goodness), with all features of App Service sharing the same authentication endpoint. This means that any authentication you setup for mobile device clients can also be used by a web site. This topic should point you in the right direction: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-auth/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have read the documentation and is very clear regarding the Xamarin app. However what I am still missing is how the MVC web site can delegate the authentication of users to the Mobile app azure service as the Xamarin does. When you say "[...] is really just a WebAPI running in Web Apps" do you mean that I can collapse the Mobile Service backed and my MVC web site in one?

Comment: Hey Lorenzo, with App Services as state by Glenn, you get either a WebAPI backend (.Net backend) or a Node.js backend (Node and Express).  With either of these two you could simply add the website files to the same directory.  However to add the point of authentication, you can do it all on the server side, so regardless of where the user attempts to login from, they get the same experience.  Have you taken a look at the documentation for Authentication with Mobile Apps? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users/

Comment: Let's say you set up authentication via Twitter (as an example) for your Mobile App Service.  Obviously, that authentication mechanism would be used in your Xamarin Forms app.  Additionally, the sample authentication could be used in your website.  Using the Mobile Apps SDK, the call in JS (in your website) would look very similar to a call in Xamarin Forms.  The actually authentication there is taken care of in the backend so it can be used anywhere.  Let me know if this explanation helps!